# Not decoding JSON response to populate collection View

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to populate a collection view with data receive from a remote PHP file.

The remote PHP file response is as follows:

```
[{"id":12,"nombre":"AGM","icono":"vCtAi1agmlogo.png"},{"id":10,"nombre":"Acer","icono":"h4QnIZacerlogo.png"},{"id":9,"nombre":"Apple","icono":"byjwZDapplelogo.png"},{"id":55,"nombre":"Cubot","icono":"xWQnfbcubotlogo.png"},{"id":110,"nombre":"Huawei","icono":"GYacqrhuaweilogo.png"},{"id":121,"nombre":"Innjoo","icono":"yWP39Ninnjoologo.png"},{"id":151,"nombre":"Lenovo","icono":"UL54jTlenovologo.png"},{"id":158,"nombre":"Majestic","icono":"ayDxNAmajesticlogo.png"},{"id":204,"nombre":"Polar","icono":"SQ3LXHpolarlogo.png"},{"id":218,"nombre":"Samsung","icono":"Vrs4hpSamsunglogo.jpg"},{"id":229,"nombre":"Sony","icono":"ZyFcI2sonylogo.png"},{"id":275,"nombre":"Xiaomi","icono":"5kRBCoxiaomilogo.png"}]
```

Here you have all methods for the collection View:

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return marcas.count

    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        print("MARCA:"+marcas[indexPath.row].nombre)
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "marca",for: indexPath) as! MarcasCollectionViewCell

        let foto_marca = marcas[indexPath.row].icono
        print(foto_marca)


        let url = URL(string: "https://../iconos/"+foto_marca)

        UIImage.loadFrom(url: url!) { image in
            cell.icono_marca.image = image

        }


        return cell


    }
```

And this is my download function to get the data:

```
   func downloadJSON(completed: @escaping () -> ()) {
        let url = URL(string: "https://.../Api.php")


        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data,response,error) in

        print("Data:",data as Any)
        print("Response:",response as Any)
        print("Error:",error as Any)

        if error == nil {
            do {
                self.marcas = try JSONDecoder().decode([Marcas].self, from: data!)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completed()
                }

            }catch{
                print("JSON Error")
            }

        }
        }.resume()


    }
```

This is the model for Marcas:

```
struct Marcas:Decodable {

    let id: String
    let nombre: String
    let icono: String

}
```

As you may see, I have included three print tags to get the response from the server.

Here you have the print outputs for each tag:

```
Data: Optional(702 bytes)

Response: Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x600000874be0> { URL: https://jogua.es/android_api/Api.php } { Status Code: 200, Headers {
    "Content-Encoding" =     (
        br
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Fri, 20 Mar 2020 17:38:10 GMT"
    );
    Server =     (
        cloudflare
    );
    Vary =     (
        "Accept-Encoding"
    );
    "cf-cache-status" =     (
        DYNAMIC
    );
    "cf-ray" =     (
        "5771348e09c868f4-CDG"
    );
    "expect-ct" =     (
        "max-age=604800, report-uri=\"https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct\""
    );
} })



Error: nil
```

At last, I a getting the JSON Error output.

What should I do to get the items for the collection View?

Comment: Don't print meaningless literal string `"JSON Error"`. Print the `error` instance. It will tell you that the type of `id` is not a string.

Comment: @vadian, I mean that the functions catchs the error because it is not able to decode the response, as you may see, there is an print(error) that outputs nil for the error

Comment: There are two possible errors. One from data task and one from the JSONDecoder. I mean the latter. Replace `print("JSON Error")` with `print(error)`

Comment: @vadian, this is the error output:  typeMismatch(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "id", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode String but found a number instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: That's what I said in my first comment: *The type of `id` is not a string.*, it's `Int`

Comment: Your `JSON` is sending an `Int` value instead of `String` for the key `id` and that is why it doesn't parse.

Comment: @vadian, solved, I have changed the model and put:  let id: Int

Comment: Please learn to read `DecodingError` messages. They are extremely comprehensive.

Comment: @vadian, yes, thank you.

Comment: @vadian are you going to put your proposal as answer to my question? Another SO user has pubished the same answer that I wrote to you as comment. What should I do?

Comment: The answer is correct. Accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the model to:

```
struct Marcas:Decodable {

let id: Int
let nombre, icono: String

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I got the same answer to my question after gettint the error printed.